# How May a Private Individual Request That a Cause for Sainthood be Opened?

Tags: catholicism, sainthood, roman-curia

In the Catholic Church, can a private individual provide evidence for, and subsequently request that a particular person's cause for Sainthood be opened?

Answer (score 3):

**How May a Private Individual Request That a Cause for Sainthood be Opened?**

Seeing that only the local ordinary of a diocese can open the canonical process for a beatification and canonization, a private layperson would have to approach the local ordinary of the diocese in which the person in question resided at the time of his death.

Private individuals after provide evidence beatification and canonization processes.

> No saint shall be named without the laborious and highly regulated process of canonization. The steps by which a person becomes a saint are carefully executed by the Church and follow a meticulous investigation. This scrutiny is called the process of canonization. It is an ancient custom and has undergone many changes and reforms through the centuries. Today, it begins on the local level, with the approval of the Holy See, and includes a careful study of the candidate’s life and writings and ends with the recognition of miracles. The validation of miracles is customarily necessary for beatification and then canonization. - [What Happens At A Canonization?](https://www.simplycatholic.com/what-happens-at-a-canonization/)

Anyone may request that a particular person's cause for Sainthood be opened, but one would have to approach the bishop of the diocese in which that person lived in.